# htaccess rewrite for query string with no filename

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the All in One calendar plugin fron time.ly which takes 4 or 5 seconds to dynamically create a css file `http://www.example.com/?ai1ec_render_css=1401363227&ver=2.0.9`

This is killing the performance of my site so I wanted to point the above at a static css page I created `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/calendar.css` using an htaccess rewrite.

But I just can't make it work correctly despite much testing and much searching of SO and Google.

This is the relevant part:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ai1ec_render_css=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/calendar.css? [L,QSA]
```

For info, here's the whole htaccess file...

```
#AuthType basic
#AuthUserFile "/path/to/passwd"
#AuthGroupFile /dev/null
#AuthName "Site Undergoing Essential Maintence - Back Soon"
#Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ai1ec_render_css=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/calendar.css? [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 4M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

php_value memory_limit 4M

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed on
    # using commands,filters etc
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript  
</ifModule>

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

Comment: Have you commented out the rule for a reason?

Comment: My mistake - I've corrected it.  The rule isn't commented in live!

Comment: Try removing the very first occurrence of "/" from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/calendar.css? [L,QSA]` - also, is there a need for the "?" after "calendar.css"?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  The first "/" was the problem.  The ? at the end means that it drops the query string altogether.  If you write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Consider to put all rules into the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` clause and to remove multiple `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives. Try to skip some next rules by using the `S` flag `[L,S=2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the very first occurrence of "/" from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/calendar.css? [L,QSA]` - this should fix the problem.

You've already defined your RewriteBase, but your RewriteRule is telling the browser to go to the folder below that and then into `wp-content/...` which will not direct it to the relevant page.